# How to sort Observable array by observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have:

```js
item: Observable<{
    title: Observable<string> | undefined;
    isSelected: boolean;
    id: string;
    position: number;
}[]>
```

I need to sort items by the value of the title but it is in Observable. I was trying to implement it in HTML:

```html
  *ngFor="let card of (cards$ | async) | orderBy ('title' | async)"
```

and by pipelines in TypeScript:

[image]

but nothing works.

Comment: Yes - look into `pipe` and the related operators.

Comment: check the question again please, maybe you are not understanding it

Comment: Well most of that information wasn't there when I read it! Please don't post screenshots of code or tiny snippets of the template, give a [mre]. What do you mean "nothing works"? You can certainly sort an array in the observable stream using pipe and map.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show that the values that I want to sort by is in Observable

Comment: The compiler will also give you the error as text, and you've clipped most of the actual content out of your screenshot anyway. Is the title of your item _actually_ an observable _within_ the observable's values? Maybe the first thing to do is flatten that out so you actually _have_ the title when you want to sort by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let us go through this problem in steps. To note, we are going to use `Observable` s' `pipe` feature to remap your data.

```
// so first we need to bring out the observable so that the entire object
// is the observable instead of just the string property

// we will initialize with some data, we will use the of operator to
// make the array an observable
const item = of([{
  {
    title: of('hello'),
    isSelected: false,
    id: 'asdfa',
    position: 234,
  },
  {
    // we make this title undefined to ensure the case solution works
    title: undefined,
    isSelected: true,
    id: 'asdf',
    position: 123,
  },
}]);

const result = item.pipe(
  // we use the exhaust map to make sure any internal obesrvable are removed
  exhaustMap((data) => {
    // the forkJoin pipe will convert an array of observables into an observable
    // of an array of elements
    return forkJoin(
      // we then map the array so that we can change each item
      data.map((element) => {
        // since each item might be undefined we null check the operation
        // we then access the title and pipe it with a map operator so
        // that we return the entire object thus turning this into the
        // desired output

        // I have noted this error on cases where the title is undefined,
        // apologies, and here is the fix below
        if(!element.title) {
          return of(element);
        }

        return element.title?.pipe(
          map((title) => ({
            // we spread the initial element and then add the title
            ...element,
            title,
          })),
        );
      }),
    );
  }),
  // so now, we should have an observable of an array of data without
  // any underlying or hidden observables

  // so then we sort the data
  map((data: any) => {
    return data.sort((a: { title: string }, b: { title: any }) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  }),
);

// we can the subscribe to this and we should get the desired result
result.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

An output of my console below with the above test data.
[image]

UPDATE:

To learn more about `rxjs` pipes and operators I would suggest
this [link](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) which shows pipe diagrams in a clear and understandablefashion.

Comment: I guess forkJoin needs at least ‘take(1)’ to emit

Comment: I agree, but I assumed its contextual...you could also use ```combineLatest``` but that might trigger many events whereas ```forkJoin``` will wait for all elements to emit at least once before finally emitting the entire result array

Comment: Without a testing example, seems about right. Might need tweaks per usage by future readers willing to read the docs

Comment: Good point, let me edit my answer and add references...

Comment: it returns just an empty array. I have tried to put take(1) after forkJoin and after exhaustMap, same result

Comment: @ДенисРедько as johnrsharpe commented, you'll need to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the source observable

Comment: i added the sample code above and tested it, it works properly on my side

Comment: @ДенисРедько I have found a mistake on my part against cases where the title is undefined and have made the correction, apologies for this...please try the solution again

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Looking again at the (updated) question, I see `title` is a nested observable that complicates things. see 
[Ashwyn Horton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68502071/8238184)

I'm keeping this answer here because it contains the discussion about `orderBy` not exiting in Angular 2+

---

I don't see `orderBy` pipe in the docs. If it's custom/from a library, please share.

You could also try:

```
this.titles$ = item.pipe(map(objs => objs.map(c => c.title).sort((a, b) => a.localCompare(b))))
```

and then `*ngFor="let title of (titles$ | async)"`

See [rxjs map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map), [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [string.localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: but how to retrieve Observable title?

Comment: as i understand orderBy is not present in angular 2+

Comment: No it is not, and you didn't ask to get the 'title', you asked to sort the items. I updated now accordingly